# Python can't find a file while it exist

Tags: python, python-2.7, arabic, persian

I wrote the following program to list last file creation time in different folders:

```
import os, os.path, time

path = raw_input("BackUp root Path: ")
folders = os.listdir(path)
report_list = dict()

for x in folders:
    if os.path.isfile(path+"\\"+x):
        folders.remove(x)

print
print
print "Last file creation time:"
for folder in folders:
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path+"\\"+folder):
        for filename in files:
            if not report_list.has_key(folder):
                report_list[folder]=time.strftime('%Y/%m/%d', time.gmtime(os.path.getctime(root+"\\"+filename)))
            this_file_date = time.strftime('%Y/%m/%d', time.gmtime(os.path.getctime(root+"\\"+filename)))
            if int(report_list[folder].translate(None,"/"))< int(this_file_date.translate(None,"/")):
                report_list[folder]= this_file_date

for folder in folders:
    if report_list.has_key(folder):
        print  "    {:<25}--->{:>15}".format(folder,report_list[folder])
    else:
        print  "    {:<25}--->{:>15}".format(folder,"Empty!")
print
print


my_filter = raw_input("Do you want to filter output? (y/n): ")
if my_filter== 'y':
    date=raw_input("Enter date(Example --> 2010/10/23): ")
    print
    print
    print "Filtered output:"
    for folder in folders:
        if report_list.has_key(folder):
            if int(report_list[folder].translate(None,"/"))< int(date.translate(None,"/")):
                print  "    {:<25}--->{:>15}".format(folder,report_list[folder])
        else:
            print  "    {:<25}--->{:>15}".format(folder,"Empty!")
```

Well, it return an error sometimes. For example when I give the address `//10.0.0.100/shares` as input, I face the following error that indicate that a file is not there!

[image]

While the file is there actually:

[image]

(Anyway searching for it, means that it was there when I create the list!)

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite the program with **Python 3.5**, and now it works fine without any error:

```
import os, os.path, time

path = input("BackUp root Path: ")
folders = os.listdir(path)
report_list = dict()

for x in folders:
    if os.path.isfile(path+"\\"+x):
        folders.remove(x)

print ()
print ()
print ("Last file creation time:")
for folder in folders:
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path+"\\"+folder):
        for filename in files:
            if not folder in report_list:
                report_list[folder]=time.strftime('%Y/%m/%d', time.gmtime(os.path.getctime(root+"\\"+filename)))
            this_file_date = time.strftime('%Y/%m/%d', time.gmtime(os.path.getctime(root+"\\"+filename)))
            if int(report_list[folder].replace("/",""))< int(this_file_date.replace("/","")):
                report_list[folder]= this_file_date

    if folder in report_list:
        print("    {:<25}{:>15}".format(folder,report_list[folder]))
    else:
        print("    {:<25}{:>15}".format(folder,"Empty!"))

print
print


my_filter = input("Do you want to filter output? (y/n): ")
if my_filter== 'y':
    date=input("Enter date(Example --> 2010/10/23): ")
    print ()
    print ()
    print ("Filtered output:")
    for folder in folders:
        if folder in report_list:
            if int(report_list[folder].replace("/",""))< int(date.replace("/","")):
                print("    {:<25}{:>15}".format(folder,report_list[folder]))
        else:
            print("    {:<25}{:>15}".format(folder,"Empty!"))
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is clearly because of using Persian characters for filename. Change your filename to English characters and it works.
Also, instead of

```
    x+"\\"+y
```

Use:

```
    os.path.join(x,y)
```

Comment: In that case, try using `(os.path.join(root,filename.decode('utf8'))`. In general, whenever you have special characters, decode('utf8') may help.